# Sequelize how to add folder for version inside Migrations folder

Tags: sequelize.js, node-modules, sequelize-cli

I'm creating a Node apps with sequelize mysql

To create table I usually using command with

```
npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name ...... etc.
```

It turns out my migration file become so many, and I want to put it in folder something goes like version of the update.

migration.version_0.1

```
-->20221221133159-create_database_sec_user

-->20221221133162-create_database_sec_agen
```

migration.version_0.2

```
-->20221221133170-create_database_sec_application

-->20221221133172-sec_user_add_new_column
```

How can I do that? I just want to simplify my migration folder so it doesn't contain too many files in one folder.

Do I need to rebuild the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Create The subfolders version1 and version2 in your migrations file.

After adding the different sub-folders in your migrations folder. **EDIT** the  .sequelizerc file and add the different paths to the sub-folders in the migrations file.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  config: path.resolve('./src/database/config', 'config.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('./src/database/models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('./src/database/seeds'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('./src/database/migrations'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('./src/database/migrations/version1'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('./src/database/migrations/version2'),

};
```

Comment: as above code exports object ,multiple "migrations-path" will overwrite with last one so only version2 migrations will run.